# how to run an already ready app in react js with npm

Tags: reactjs

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

This is how I created a react app. But if I get an already ready app in react how will I run it?

Comment: npm install and then npm run start (see package.json if npm run start doesn't work)

Comment: why did you add npm start ,while creating a react app

Comment: Development:
> npm install
> npm start

Productiion*:
./build/index.html

*if build folder doesn't exist then execute:
> npm run build

Comment: Please mark as an answer if helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside the project directory run: `npm install`, this will install all of your project dependencies, and after that, you can start the app with the `npm start` command.

Answer (score 0):

*Development:*

```
npm install  
npm start
```

*Production**:

**./build/index.html**

*if build folder doesn't exist then execute:

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal,

Go to Project Directory

Use this command

```
npm install
```

It will install all the dependencies that are necessary to run this project.

Now run the development server

```
npm start
```